# Can we add iOS-like scrollbars to this site?

Tags: feature-request

I know that people using Lion will have nice, pretty scrollbars, but what about those of us who don't have Lion? I was wondering if we can add some iOS-like scrollbars to the site. I think that it would add more personality to the site.
Example [here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/):

[image: custom scrollbar]

Obviously we'd have to make the scrollbars grey...but that's simple.

EDIT: Here's the code:

```
/* For the "inset" look only */
html {
    overflow: auto;
}
body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    bottom: 1px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
/* Start Scrollbar */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
} 
/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 45px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4);
}
/* End Scrollbar */
```

Which gives you this:

[image: Lion scrollbar]

Comment: Lion scrollbars are ugly; please don't inflict them on people who have chosen not to subject themselves to Lion's aesthetic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I copied the code from above into a user stylesheet on [userstyles.org](http://userstyles.org/).

If you want to try the scrollbars out, you can install [Stylish for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) or [for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/?src=external-userstyleshome).
Go to [the stylesheet](http://userstyles.org/styles/58387/ask-different-lion-scrollbars) and click Install.

---

Here's my personal opinion:
While I don't think that Lion's scrollbars are ugly, I do think that people should be able to use whatever scrollbars they like, be that their OS's scrollbars, their browser's scrollbars, or a custom stylesheet. Generally, sites that override that without a very good reason end up just being annoying

Comment: Ok, sounds good, Nathan! Thanks for the stylesheet too!